# How to authenticate signed android .apk?

Tags: android, digital-signature

I signed the android application via Eclipse with my Keystore.

What I want to do is I want to authenticate that this application is signed by me because I want only this application to access my PHP webservice. 
What I thought of is that 
1. I need to have the public key that corresponding to the private key 
2. Use public key to verify if the application is signed by me

So my questions are 
1. Is my thinking correct? 
2. How do I authenticate the signed .adk? 
3. jarsigner -verbose -verify android.apk is for verifying the integrity of android.apk but it does not authenticate right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you are mixing the signature of the apk and the authentication to your php server from your app.

To be sure that your app is the only one accessing your web services you can actually get a token from Google Play Services and then validates that web token against google's certificate on your php server!

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Answer (score 0):

The signing of the APK tells Android that the person who signed version 2 is the same person who signed version 1.  It doesn't authenticate who that actually is, it just assures that the same person signed all versions of an app.  Its a security method around downloading updates.

If you want to authenticate to a webservice, you won't use this key.  In face using that key anywhere else would be a bad idea for security.  Instead, you want to use https for all calls to the webservice to encrypt the channel.  Then you can do something simple, like sending a secret key as 1 parameter.  That will give you a baseline amount of security.  If you want more, you really need a secret not known by the apk (such as a password entered by the user).

Comment: I thought of sending the signature and hash value.
Then webservice will use public key to decrypt the signature and compare with the hash value.
Can this be done?